# Выражение "качать права"

Tags: фразеология

Качать права - доказывать свою правоту, лезть со своим уставом в чужой монастырь. Одним словом, это выражение знают все.
Но вот интересно, почему права именно качают? Это выражение имеет под собой какую-то смысловую основу или просто, как говорится, к слову?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь качать- раскачивать, шатать, лишать прочности и незыблемости.

КАЧАТЬ ПРАВА - уголовный жаргон. В зоне не только права, и режим качают, т.е. раскачивают, шатают.Был жёсткий и для всех обязательный, но вот явился кто-то и начал качать.

Качать права - это означает выяснять отношения. Разоблачать.  Качают права только воры в законе и только у своих. У них права - авторитет, он даёт право верховодить, но как только кто-то выявляет, что этот авторитетный вор где-то "накосячил",поступил не по воровскому закону - ему предъявляют претензии, "качают права", теперь у него нет права командовать всеми.

Но из жаргона выражение пришло в наш быт, мы стали употреблять его, не понимая специфики воровской жизни, появилось значение качать права - проявлять неуважение к установленным порядкам, грубостью и  силой доказывать свои права. Как мускулы качают, накачивают, так и права себе накачивают.Совместились зоновские и уличные представления и проникли даже в учреждения, там тоже права качают.

Answer (score 1):

> Но вот интересно, **почему права именно
> качают?**

По-моему, рождение этого жаргонизма может быть связано с символом правосудия -- весами Фемиды, на которых *судья* взвешивает доводы в пользу обвиняемого и против него. Они (весы) ведь при этом качаются!

У Мокиенко есть:

> **Качать права**
>
> 1. Жарг. угол., Разг. Скандалить; отстаивать свою позицию, грубо
>    подавляя волю другого; выдвигать свои
>    условия и требовать их исполнения.
> 2. Жарг. угол. **Разбирать конфликты** между ворами на сходке.
>
> http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/proverbs/38012/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C

Ну а разбор конфликтов -- тот же суд.